# Accessing Temp Directory On Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

im new in this page and i love the answers nice job, with all the help of users, im new on python and wanna make a print of dir in a entry or label doesnt matter for example:

```
def directory(): os.listdir('/')
files=StringVar()
files.set(directory)
entry=Entry(root, textvariable=files).grid()
```

obviously in tkinter, the last code make a "print" a list of directories, but make me a list horizontal with this ',' for each folder different, i want it vertical list on this "entry" or "label", suppose later need a scroll bar but, there no is a problem, and make the same for temporal folder on windows look like that...

```
def directory(): os.listdir('%temp%')
    files=StringVar()
    files.set(directory)
    entry=Entry(root, textvariable=files).grid()
```

but this %temp% doesnt works directly on python how can i make a listdir of folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since displaying the contents of a directory is going to generally require multiple lines of text, one for each item in it, you have to use a`tk.Label`or`tk.Text`widget since a `tk.Entry`can only handle a *single* line of text.

In addition you'll need to convert the`list`that `os.listdir()` returns into a multi-line string before setting its`text`option. Regardless, in order to be use your`directory()` function needs to return a value to be useful.

The following code does these basic things and shows how to expand the value of the`%temp%`environment variable using`os.path.expandvars()`. Alternatively, you can get the same value by using the[`tempfile.gettempdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir)function Sukrit recommended.

```
import os
from Tkinter import *

def directory(folder):
    return '\n'.join(os.listdir(folder))  # turn list into multiline string

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        files = directory(os.path.expandvars('%temp%'))
        self.label = Label(root, text=files)
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: oh my God, thank you very much for this example, is just what i needed, now see that deal i did not know command module "os", have  a nice day ! ;D.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but now I have a new question, after various tests, I realize that is maybe a "listbox" a label, I tried to change Label for Listbox or Scrolledtext..
but the code does not work, that I can do to make it?

Comment: Thank you. Well, making it into a `Listbox` would involve quite a few changes. However if you post a separate follow-up question, I or someone else will probably answer it. You should include the code for your failed attempt(s).

Comment: @martineau : Expanding the `%temp%` variable is Windows specific whereas the `tempfile` module provides an OS independent approach.

Comment: @Sukrit: Yes, I know, and I referenced using the `tempfile` module as suggested in your answer. Neither of us mentioned it was a more portable way to do it. I instead chose to put effort into answering on the rest of the OP's question regarding displaying things in `Tkinter`.